# google contacts api v3 using property-Key

Tags: google-contacts-api

I'm trying to limit the amount of information returned from a get by using the extended properties and projections (property-KEY), but I get the same information regardless of what I specify in the get request.

For example, from OAuth playground

```
//www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/thin?v=3.0&max-results=10&q=mytest@gmail.com

//www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/property-familyName?v=3.0&max-results=10&q=mytest@gmail.com

//www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?v=3.0&max-results=10&q=mytest@gmail.com
```

Am I interpreting the API correctly for projections?  I expected to get only the family-Name when I specify a projection of property-familyName?

Comment: any luck figuring what property-key doesn't work?